# Get last and first record using rank()

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I need to get first and last record (ordered by `Date` column) from table for certain `SSID`. It is not a problem if there is more records with same max or min date. All I need is `union all`.

I am getting last record having `max(date)` with:

```
with c as (
    select *, rnk = rank() over (partition by Date order by Date ASC)
    from table
    where SSID = '00921834800'
)
select top 1 Date, City, Title
from c
order by Date desc
```

How to I get first record (`min(Date)`) as well (same thing only with `order by Date asc`) with single select and without using ranking again?

I'm using MSSQL 2017.

Comment: `partition by Date order by Date ASC` is a bit pointless. If you are partitioning the data by the value of `date` then all the values in that partition have the same value for `date`, so ordering by it makes no sense. You should be ordering by another column.

Comment: You need two rows even if they are same (e.g. only one record exists for a given id)?

Comment: @SalmanA i need all rows in case there is same date.

Comment: @Larnu The function 'rank' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY and I don't have any other column which could be used to ORDER BY. Idea is to do single oredering and use it in 2 unioned selects...if possible.

Comment: But if you are ranking every row by the same value in the partition then **every** row has the rank `1`.... You might as well have written `rnk = 1`.

Comment: That's why I posted this question...

Comment: And it's why I stated that your `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` columns should be different.

Comment: Tired all combinations - gets me improper ranking. I guess this rank over partition is not usable for my case. I'll have to go with Salmans answer

Comment: You can do `ORDER BY (SELECT 1)`, although either way the ordering is going to be arbitrary. Perhaps you don't need `partition by`

Comment: The semi-colon is a statement **terminator**, but a "beginator". Use them consistently and you don't need this lazy kludge of adding one immediately before a CTE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
; with c as (
    select *,
      rnk = rank() over (partition by Date order by Date ASC),
      rnk2 = rank() over (partition by Date order by Date desc)
    from table
    where SSID= '00921834800'
)
select Date,
City,
Title
from c
where rnk = 1 or rnk2 = 1
order by Date desc
```

Comment: When using the same column in the `partition by` as in the `order by` there is no sorting done, as each partition will have the same single value

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following query:

```
select * from (select top 1 with ties * from t where ssid = '00921834800' order by date) as a
union all
select * from (select top 1 with ties * from t where ssid = '00921834800' order by date desc) as b
```

Comment: It looks like they want all the records that match the same `min` and `max` `Date` values, so a `top 1` will not return all required records

Comment: `top 1 with ties` will do it.

Comment: you should define where to insert columns which are needed. I assume it's inner select.

Comment: inner or outer, does not matter.

Comment: Can you please comment this solution in regard with speed of execution in comparison with yours: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70954853/2119941 . Please read my comments below that answer.

Comment: @Hrvoje window functions show much better plan but run both queries just to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

One other solution is :

```
with 
c as 
(
select *, 
       rank() over (partition by Date order by Date ASC) AS RNK,
       count() OVER (partition by Date) AS CNT
from   table
where  SSID= '00921834800')
select Date, City, Title 
from   c
WHERE  RNK = 1
   OR  CNT = RNK
order by Date desc
```

Comment: Smart. If you can proof that this is faster than chosen solution I'll pick your answer. I believe it could be since sorting is costing me most. I'm joining this with over SSID with table that has 2 millions records and I'll have to do that repeatedly over n other tables each month. So speed is imperative for me.

Comment: I need both max and min values so I believe that in the end it should be AND not OR.